# count function should return 0 or null if no row selected

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written below query

```
select process_status_count 
from (select count(*) as process_status_count from prod.process_status) 
where process_status_count <> 18;
```

Requirement: i want `process_status_count` should return 0 if condition "`process_status_count <> 18`" does not fulfill (`process_status_count` is 18).

but `process_status_count` is returning no result (not a null also).

Please suggest what change i need to do so it will result zero or null if `process_status_count  = 18`.

Comment: count can return 0 but not null

Answer (score 1):

Use case statement;

```
select case when process_status_count = 18 then 0 else process_status_count end  from (select count(*) as process_status_count from sidewinder.process_status);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: below query i used and its working fine:                                    select case when process_status_count = 18 then 0 else process_status_count end  from (select count(*) as process_status_count from sidewinder.process_status);

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query,

```
SELECT CASE process_status_count WHEN 18 THEN process_status_count ELSE 0 END
FROM(
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS process_status_count 
     FROM prod.process_status
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select count(*), decode(count(*), 18, count(*), 0) fullfill_cond
  2  from user_objects
  3  /

  COUNT(*) FULLFILL_COND                                                        
---------- -------------                                                        
       937             0                                                        

SQL> select count(*), decode(count(*), 937, count(*), 0) fullfill_cond
  2  from user_objects
  3  /

  COUNT(*) FULLFILL_COND                                                        
---------- -------------                                                        
       937           937
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this would help you :

```
with process_status
as
(
select 'Y' as process_status_count from dual
connect by level <=18
)
select decode(count(process_status_count),18,0,count(process_status_count)) as status   
from   process_status
```